# Old laptop power brick > DIY current regulator > 20w COB LED - will it do what I think it will?

Tags: current-limiting, lm317

I have a salvaged 20W battery-powered work light: the housing and LED inside. Before the electronics and the original 7.4v dead battery got tossed, I hooked up a somewhat discharged 7.4v battery to it and measured 18.5v / 1.2A to the LED itself. (Yeah, I should have kept the electronics but I didn't.)

I have an old 21v charger supply from an old laptop. It puts out 2.5A.

If I make a current regulator with a LM317 and resisters (or some other fast/easy way) and put that regulator between the power brick and the LED, will this actually do what I think it will?

Will it let the LED have only the amps I 'set' with resisters (in my case I will set it at 1A) and vary the voltage as needed from an  minimum and the full 21v of the power brick?

^

THE PREVIOUS SENTENCE IS WHAT I THINK WILL HAPPEN.

I know this is a silly question to many who already know about these things. I DON'T already know about this and am not clearly understanding the things I am reading about it online - so I am asking here if I am understanding what these basic types of current regulators will do.

Comment: The regulator must drop 2.5V at 1.2A and your LED was drawing 22.5W so you can do this many ways with 3W dropped to achieve this. The easiest is a 2.5v/1.2=2.1 Ohm 3W or better 5W series resistor.

Comment: OK, so when I wrote "Will it let the LED have only the amps I 'set' with resisters (in my case I will set it at 1A) and vary the voltage as needed from an minimum and the full 21v of the power brick?" I did not EXPLICITLY STATE that this is what I think will happen. Nevermind that it's pretty clear that this is what the wording means in the context of the rest of the question... Ugh. I will add, explicitly, that this is the case.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist - I have read that the amps will vary as the resister gets hotter, and don't want to fry the LED, so I had been thinking the current limiter was the right thing to do. No?

Comment: @111936 The resistor IS the current limiter. You could also use BJT current limiting circuits. But these would ALSO have to dissipate the same amount. It's just that it might be spread out over more parts. But the required voltage drop (before the LED lamp) across any circuit (in volts) times the current through that circuit (in amps) equals the watts that must be dissipated. And it does NOT matter if that is one resistor or 5 resistors and 2 BJTs. The power must dissipate. You just get to choose your poison, so to speak.

Comment: No , The LEDs are NTC -3mV/‘C  and the resistor will be PTC 3ppm/‘C.  So if a 250mV variation on a 2.5V drop is 10% , you can choose 2.3 Ohm for safety margin or add a PTC polyfuse to the board near LEDs only .  Or get a whack( 25) of 0.1 ohm 1/4 W resistors . (Cheap)

Comment: Just a general observation: I am having to google everything that is in acronym form in these comments. "NTC" "NPT" "mV/'C" "3ppm/'C" "whack(25)" etc. Obviously I'm a noob and mentally challenged by all this, but I think it's important for you guys to realise this effect of using "already knowledgable" wording/abbreviations on non-knowers like me. 10 minutes for me to translate that comment.

Comment: @111936  Surely that is how you learn.  Now you know what those TLAs mean :)

Comment: @111936 - On the one hand you complain that folks use acronyms you don't understand, and they should take your noobness into account. At the same time, in your first comment, you objected that folks wanted you to be explicit when you relied on context. You can't have it both ways. We have no way to know the state of your knowledge, and that sets the context for judging "implied". Often, people will try to infer your level from the details of the question, but as you know, that doesn't always work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said the LED lamp is \$20\:\text{W}\$ and I'll assume that's because it's written down, somewhere. Your measurements are consistent with the rating, too. So I'm going to accept the numbers you developed for the LED lamp.

Your laptop charger system is another issue. Modern ones are sophisticated enough that they may require some kind of communication in order to active their power supply activity. If so, you may have some difficulties getting it to drive your LED lamp. But let's assume that's not a problem, here.

Given the voltage rating of your power supply and its compliance current, it would seem to be a decent fit. Probably the easiest thing to do is to buy a few \$10\:\text{W}\$ ceramic resistors, with values from say \$3.3\:\Omega\$ down to \$1.8\:\Omega\$. Start with the highest valued resistor and place it in series with the LED lamp and your power supply (with correct polarity!) Measure the voltage across the \$3.3\:\Omega\$ resistor. Divide the voltage you measured by this resistance to work out the current through the resistor (and therefore through the LED lamp.) If this current is at or below the figure of \$1.2\:\text{A}\$ (or so close it doesn't matter much), then you have worked out a match-up. If the current is too low, then replace that resistor with the next lower value and repeat until you get the right current.

You could go to the trouble of adding a pair of BJTs to provide a current limiter. But there probably isn't any point. You still have to dissipate some excess power either way and the main advantage for the BJTs is supporting a wider range of source voltages -- something you don't care to do. So it's probably pointless worrying about anything more than a simple resistor to limit the current with your existing power supply.

---

Just in case you might have gotten some numbers wrong, it might be a good idea to also include at least an \$18\:\Omega\$ and perhaps even a \$33\:\Omega\$ resistor in your package. (\$10\:\text{W}\$ also.) Put one of them in series with your LED lamp first, just to make sure. Switch it on for a few moments and check the voltage across it, quickly. Let the resistor warm up for a few seconds, too. You should be able to verify that the current is fairly low by making the calculation above and also should be able to verify that the dissipation in the resistor is modest -- it doesn't heat up too fast.

---

If for any reason any of the resistors appear to heat up very quickly (which may happen if the LED lamp isn't dropping much voltage), then turn things off immediately and do NOT let the resistor get too hot. In this case, it would appear that your LED lamp needs a much larger voltage drop across a resistor and this will require you reporting more detailed results from these experiments before a better answer can be offered.

Comment: TonyEErocketscientist's comment above about using just a resister matches yours - but so many people (online) say not to use just a resister for a COB LED because it changes what Amps get through as it heats up. So many things I've read say that this is a bad thing to do (just a resister) so I have gone down the current limiter road. Are all these others online wrong? Is my case special somehow because I have a constant voltage source? Aargh, I'm just not getting this.

Comment: 20W rating is from label on the lamp. Charger puts out voltage and current when you connect things to it or even just a multimeter The LED on it's own lights up pretty bright with no resister or anything.

Comment: @111936 I think it is safe enough to experiment. The measurements you take and your observations from those experiments would add a lot to a new question, should it be needed. The current will drift around because the LED lamp heats up and also because the resistor heats up. Both. But I think you are able to experiment here. Start out with a value that seems close, when "cold", and then wait and let things heat up a bit. Measure again. If this isn't right, adjust with a new resistor and go through the process again. It's not rocket science and you won't hurt much trying it out.

Comment: @111936 If you are serious about a simple current limit circuit, that's easy to design. But beforehand, I think you should try out a short experiment with your power supply, a resistor, and the LED lamp. Something it appears you haven't yet done. It would go a long way in removing some of the uncertainties in your writing and situation if you performed some experiments with the power supply you have and the lamp you have. Two different resistor values plus some measurements immediately and then sometime after things warm up would mostly nail down any questions.

Comment: The assurance that I won't 'hurt it' is helpful. I'll do some resister playing then and come back here to report later this evening or tomorrow (have to go out to get the resisters).  Can you please edit/add a little bit at the beginning of your answer to directly say something like "Your thinking on X is wrong, in this way, and are sort of correct abut Y in this way" so that I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: @111936 Unfortunately, I can't say anything about your thinking. I can only speak for what is in my head, not yours. I could remove the entire first paragraph (already done), since that paragraph is really unnecessary. I do think you should NOT consider the LM317. (I could write that much. But then I'd have to explain why.)